# Can we limit the Scope of a dependency with hilt in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I just upgraded to the hilt and previously was working with the dagger.

**What I am looking for?**

I have two activities Activity **A and B** and I have two Recycler Adapters **AdapterA and AdapterB**.

I want to provide the **AdapterA** instance to **Activity A** and **AdapterB** instance to **Activity B** with @Inject.

I am not using @Singleton annotation but I don't know why my both adapters are being injected in both activities, apparently, They should not work like that.
**What I have done so far.**

```
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.components.ActivityComponent

@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class CurrencyModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideCurrencyAdapter(): CurrencyRatesAdapter {
        return CurrencyRatesAdapter(mutableListOf())
    }
}
```

In Activity A

```
@Inject
    lateinit var currencyRatesAdapter: CurrencyRatesAdapter
```

Please suggest to me that how can I limit my adapter dependency scope to just one Activity?
**Thank you**

Comment: Add `@ActivityScoped` on `provideCurrencyAdapter()`.

Comment: Thank you AMD If I used @ActivityScoped so, my adapter will be injected only in Activities but  I want to limit the scope to a single activity.

Comment: Your question is not super clear, what do you mean that they are both getting injected? Do you mean that they CAN be inject with both of the adapters or that they ARE injected?